# Keeping tests to start with known state - What about multithreading?

Tags: java, testng

I'm trying to cleanup my tests by always resetting to a known state before each test. In JUnit it seems that the best way to do this is to have a `setup()` method that sets the values for some fields. When running tests in parallel the field is always correct since each test is executed in a new instance of the test.

However in TestNG this doesn't seem to be the case. According to a [post on their mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/testng-users/browse_thread/thread/f942b55a4a730395), setting fields in `@BeforeMethod` in a multithreaded testing doesn't guarantee their value.

As I need the classes I'm testing to be in a known state, is there a cleaner solution to this than using DataProvider or saying "Don't ever run tests in mulithreaded mode"?

Comment: What about using `ThreadLocal` as instance variable in TestNG test case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one difference between TestNG and JUnit in this specific area: JUnit will create a brand new instance of your test before each test method, TestNG will not.

What this means is that with TestNG, values stored in fields by test methods will be preserved between invocations, which is very useful if this object is complex and takes time to create. It also helps speed up test runs since you don't have to recreate this state from scratch every time.

If you want this state to be reset every time, simply put the initialization code in @BeforeMethod, like you do with JUnit (except it's called @Before).

As for multithreading, I don't understand why you are saying that there is no guarantee about that value, can you be more specific?

Comment: Since fields are shared between all tests, when you execute tests in multiple threads the field might be reset halfway through as another test method fires up

Comment: True, but you usually TestNG in parallel mode to test your production code in a multithreaded environment, not the test code itself. You also use parallelism in TestNG to speed up your tests, so the assumption here is that they are independent from each other. TestNG lets you specify various threading strategies for that purpose.

Comment: Okay. After your answer I did move one of my big test classes to a @BeforeMethod layout and it does work. However I'm still worried about others executing the tests with multiple threads. I'm about to add a big warning to the class Javadoc about it and pray that it works.

Comment: Just like with many things, praying with multithreaded code is not going to help much :-) More seriously, if several of your test methods are modifying the same field, just use synchronization judiciously, but this should be very rare. Please email testng-users if you have more specific questions, I'll be happy to answer there.